# Unity 3D Character Customization

Tags: unity-game-engine, model, blender, maya

Lets say I create many different 3D objects (Arms, legs, body, head). How would I go about making it so all of them can connect to form a body. And after the body is formed make it so they all animate in the same way. Can anyone help me in the right direction with tutorials or links on these topics?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some good tutorials:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3oVAXhvQl0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ch1aJljEYp4

https://medium.com/@larissaredeker/3d-character-customization-fd95a1d57ae

And here a reddit user's answer(Named **DankP3**):

For body sliders you will probably want to look at blendshapes, this is done in the modelling programme. The more blendshapes you have the more complex it will get. eg. 'normal' 'thin' and 'muscular' bodies at one scale of variation and thicker eye brows at the other.... Of note though, facial morphs don't affect most clothes!

I think one of the most challenging parts will be that using the same animation on a thin character and a muscle bound character will not look good so some significant animation work may be required.

I'd probably apply hairstyle in the same way as clothes (see below), but colour can be manged for hair easily through code, swapping base colours, or textures.

For clothes, you rig to the same skeleton as the character (and you will need the same blendshapes to fit the body or if your body is to change shape). A lot of people put all clothes in the same model and turn them on and off as required (this intuitively seems messy), but looping through the bone array on the meshrenderer is not difficult and contrary to what the other reply says you don't need to match bones by angle and position. if you rig correctly, you can just swap, rather than match, the bones in the clothes mesh renderer for those on the character model when the clothes are put on and you are all done.

Again, all credit goes to **DankP3**
You can see his answer [HERE](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/8rba30/can_you_create_a_character_customization_system/).